# I want to send this data {{quote}} to the app.js side

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, nodes

Previously, the value was in an input tag, and I could access it on the app.js page through the name field of the input tag. The type was set to submit.
I converted it to a

tag and now can't seem to figure out a way to access it in the app.js side.

The line of code:

```html
<label class = "putItInLine" id="innerContent">Quote:
  <p class = "putItInLine" type="text" name="quoteSelected">
    {{quote}}
  </p>
</label>
```

The app.js side is here:

```js
const form = req.body;

if (form.userSelectionQuotePage === 'DELETE') {
  // Id would come out as a string, so but in the database,
  // we need it to be as integer, so thats why we've done typecasting
  let id = parseInt(form.id);
  quotes_db.run(`DELETE
                 FROM quotes
                 WHERE quote = ?`, form.quoteSelected,
    function (err) {
      if (!err) {
        res.redirect('/quotes');
      } else {
        console.log('QUOTE NOT DELETED', err);
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: add new input with hidden type, if you don’t  want to let user changing value but send to sever again

Comment: If you just want to access the text in a tag, use dom query to select it, and than access it by innerHTML attr